# Adding to to-many / many-to-many core data relationship

Tags: cocoa, core-data, tags, nsarraycontroller

I have 2 Entities, related by a many-to-many relationship.

```
Thing<<->>Tag
```

There is one NSArrayController controlling the entity "Tag", bound to the managedObjectContext. By the array controllers add: and remove: action i can add instances of tag to the collection.

There is a second NSArrayController controlling "Thing" entities, also bound to the managedObjectContext.

So each of the controllers manages *all* instances of their entity.

Now, let's say there are 5 "tag" and 3 "thing" instances already created by their array controllers.
I'd like to link individual tags to a thing. I just want to create the relationship between an existing thing to an existing tag instance.

- Is addObject: of NSArrayController the right method for that? Or does it create a new managedObject?
- Would it be equivalent to:

  ```
  NSMutableSet *tags = [aThing mutableSetValueForKey:@"tags"];
  [tags addObject:existingTag];
  ```

  ?
- Is there some best practice for a tagging system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it helpful (in the latest version of Xcode) to select the entity in the core data modeller, and then go to the file menu, and select new file -> Core Data -> NSManagedObject subclass.  It automatically creates a class with the necessary members AND ALSO methods for adding objects in the toMany relationships.

If you've done that, then you just need to get ahold of the `thing` instance to which you want to add a `tag` and you can call the method declared for you to do so.  How that method is named is obvious from the header file generated.

Comment: Thank You very much. Would this then be the same as using an NSArrayController with ist add: method?

Comment: Adding an object to an NSArrayController only tells the NSArrayController about it.  If you want the added object to be visible at the UI you need to do that.  Separately, you need to add the `tag` to its `thing` and the `thing` to the `tag`.  This is where the auto generated add methods come in.